# LaTeX to Markdown converter

Tags: conversion, markdown

Does there exist open source LaTeX converters that produce Markdown, in the same manner tools like latex2html does?

Comment: `pandoc` is often mentioned.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html) is what you need. This tool helps you convert any markup format to another one including from latex to markdown.

For your need, first you need to [install pandoc into your system](http://pandoc.org/installing.html) (available for all MacOS, Windows, Linux) and then use this command line

```
pandoc -s example4.tex -o example5.md
```

You can also convert your texts online by using a tool provided [here](http://pandoc.org/try/).

Comment: The issue is that it does not show the images and also does not support multiple column style ...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pandoc -s example4.tex -o example5.md`

Comment: On Windows, you can install pandoc very easily using scoop

Comment: This worked as a very half-way solution for me. Had to do a bit of revision afterwards, but it definitely saved me some time compared to doing the whole job manually

Comment: Work nice but it is not able convert tables in markdown succesfully

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

This project, https://github.com/loopspace/latex-to-internet, provides a class which produces text output in a variety of different formats.  It comes with a huge number of caveats, but it does work.

The underlying principle is that "*The only thing that understands TeX is TeX itself*" so it uses TeX to parse the document and produce the desired output.